# Query to get batch range on Size column not using ntile

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are working on large set of records for process. we are doing batch wise process using NTILE Function right now.

Please check on attached image example.

We are using currently NTILE function to make range then using ID column in between to process.

As per new requirement, we have to make range based on Size column. 100 GB per batch.

For example:

```
Batch 1 : 1 has 100 size So ID: 1 record only.
Batch 2 : 2,3,4,5 (Total 100 GB) 
Batch 3 : 6 ID has > 100 so 1 record only
etc.
```

Please check attached screenshot for more understand.

My Findings but not giving exact solution:

```html
DECLARE @intBatchSize BIGINT = 100;
SELECT  y.ID, y.FileSize, y.RunningTotal
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (y.RunningTotal / @intBatchSize) + 1) batch
FROM    (SELECT i.ID, i.FileSize
               ,RunningTotal = SUM(i.Size) OVER (ORDER BY i.ID) -- RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
         FROM   dbo.Table1 AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
        ) y
ORDER BY y.ID;
```

Comment: seems that you forgot to attach the screenshot

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to edit the question now. But the point is to have new batch number, once we reach total filesize to 100 GB. So that we can have nearly 100 GB of filesize in each batch. This will be in contrast to the batches generated by NTILE, which will distribute files unevenly across batches, where few batches will have large files and few will have small files. Hope, I am clear in my requirement.